# Failed to get D-Bus connection

Tags: debian, apache2, ping, failover

I have a kimsufi server at OVH running with a proxmox 2.3 and an ipfailover
When the i start the server is on the network;
on the other hand my container CT OpenVZ debian 7 makes an error if I start the network and / or apache2:

```
vzctl enter 100
/etc/init.d/networking restart
Restarting networking (via systemctl): networking.service Failed to get D-Bus connection: No such file or directory

/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
Restarting apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.serviceFailed to get D-Bus connection: No such file or directory

with ping google.com i have :  
ping: unknown host google.com
```

Have you an idea ?
thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

Debian ist a systemd-controlled operating system. In a container there is no systemd daemon on PID-1 by default.

The old init-scripts "restart" is forwarded to "systemctl restart" and systemctl wants to talk to the systemd daemon. That's where the error message comes from.

Solutions would be

- use a container operating system that is not systemd-controlled
- run a systemd in the container or forward the requests to the host systemd
- use [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) to handle systemctl executions without systemd